# JSON merge two responses in android

Tags: android, json

I am using JSON to get response from my server. 
This is code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpResponse response2;
        try {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(GlobalConfig.getMagazineUrl());
            HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet(GlobalConfig.getMagazinePagesUrl(1));

            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                                            (GlobalConfig.getAuthString()).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
            request2.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                    (GlobalConfig.getAuthString()).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            response2 = httpclient2.execute(request2);
            StatusLine statusLine2 = response2.getStatusLine();

            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK && statusLine2.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                response2.getEntity().writeTo(out2);

                out.close();
                out2.close();
                return parser(out.toString(), out2.toString());
```

As you can see in `parser(out.toString(), out2.toString())` I return both responses as String. I would like to know how I can merge this two JSON responses in one. I don't want to merge two strings, I need merge two JSON respons in one big response. This is possible? If yes how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps thats what you want:

```
...
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("response1", new JSONObject(out.toString()));
json.put("response2", new JSONObject(out2.toString()));
```

Now *return* either `json.toString()` or `json` depending on the return type.